# Trying to write a loop that makes a calculation for every vector in a dataframe

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to write a loop that will perform a calculation on every value of every vector in a dataframe. Essentially, I am trying to standardize the values in the dataframe. I am trying to find the mean of each vector. Then I subtract that mean from the individual data values in each vector. Then I want to divide the difference (data value subtract mean of vector) by the standard deviation of the vector.
The expected result is that the mean is 0 and the standard deviation 1 for every individual vector in the dataframe.

I tried using this code:

```
for(i in colnames(metabolites)) {
  metabolites<-metabolites %>% 
   (i-(mean(i)))/sd(i)
}
```

But it returns this error:

```
> for(i in colnames(metabolites)) {
+   metabolites<-metabolites %>% 
+    (i-(mean(i)))/sd(i)
+ }
Error in i - (mean(i)) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(i) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Tried writing the loop a couple different ways. Expected it to produce a standardized dataset where every vector has its own mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1

Comment: Your code is passing the column names (i) which are characters, as the argument to `mean`, hence the error "non-numeric argument". You may want to look at the `scale` function for an easier way to do this.

Comment: @neilfws What should I used instead of column names?

Comment: You could try something like `metabolites[, i] <- (metabolites[, i] - mean(metabolites[, i])) / sd(metabolites[, i])`. Don't use the pipe to assign back to `metabolites` as you are now, that won't work. You may also want to look at `dplyr::mutate` as a way to alter the columns.

Comment: OK! I should add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the for-loop, `colnames(metabolites)[i]` is each column name, a character variable. So you are passing the name of the column to `mean`, not the column values. Hence the error "non-numeric argument".

Column values are accessed using `metabolites[, i]` so something like this should work:

```
for(i in colnames(metabolites)) {
  metabolites[, i] <- (metabolites[, i] - mean(metabolites[, i])) / sd(metabolites[, i])
}
```

You may also want to look at the `scale` function, or `dplyr::mutate` as a way to alter column values.